# Telemetry sampling without affecting the errors/failures

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I want to log a percentage of the success calls in app insights.
I came across this post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling and I think Fixed-rate sampling is appropriate here. But does this affect all logging equally? Will some errors/failures no longer be logged?

I am looking for a solution that logs a percentage of the success calls, but keeps all failed requests/errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is supported out of the box, but you can write your own `ITelemetryProcessor`.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor

Application Insights in .NET uses a chain of telemetry processors that you can use to filter telemetry, so you can write your own that checks the `resultCode` (I think that's what Application Insights calls the HTTP status code, but you'll have to double check) of a request telemetry object, and approves it if it's 500 (or 5xx) but only has a 10% chance of sending it if it's 2xx or 3xx. You can override the `OKToSend()` method to perform the above check on the `ITelemetry` input, and return true / false accordingly.

Maybe something like (I wrote this in the browser, it won't necessarily work flawlessly as-is):

```
// Approves 500 errors and 10% of other telemetry objects
private bool OKtoSend (ITelemetry telemetry)
{
    if (telemetry.ResponseCode == 500) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int filter = rnd.Next(1, 11);
        return filter == 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot call item["resultCode"] as I get "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type ITelemetry".
item as DependencyTelemetry() has a ResultCode property (string). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.datacontracts.dependencytelemetry.resultcode?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: @Wouter  I'd guess you want the `RequestTelemetry` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.datacontracts.requesttelemetry?view=azure-dotnet) class instead of `DependencyTelemetry`, since you are logging requests, for which the correct property for HTTP response code would be `ResponseCode`.

Comment: Seems like everything passes the ITelemetryProcessor. I'll have to treat them separately.

Comment: I have another question. Everything needs to be treated separately. I don't want to throw away dependencies that are related to an exception (otherwise there may be incomplete data to debug). Is there a way to keep everything together or figure out which dependencies are related to exceptions/errors?

Comment: @Wouter in one of the Rails apps where I use a lot of Application Insights telemetry, there's a custom logger which sends custom traces to app insights and converts arbitrary objects to JSON, which I've used to supplement the default exception-catching with custom data. I don't love that solution and strongly suspect there are better ways you could do it with a custom telemetry processor, but it's an option.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Any good links that I can take a look at?

Comment: @Wouterday-to-day I mostly deal with their API via the [ruby](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Ruby) and [node](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js) libraries so for .NET I'm not positive, but this doc looks pretty close: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-trace-logs, you can use something like `System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceWarning("Slow response - database01");` or `telemetry.TrackTrace("Slow response - database01");` to send custom telemetry to app insights that supplement your automatic logging.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude failed events from being subject to sampling, (while doing sampling for everything else) write a `TelemetryInitializer` with this logic.

```
public class PreventSamplingForFailedTelemetryInitializer: ITelemetryInitializer
{
  public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
  {
        if(failed)
        {
            // Set to 100, so that actual SamplingProcessors ignore this from sampling considerations.
            ((ISupportSampling)telemetry).SamplingPercentage = 100;
        }
   }
}

(Make sure to add this TelemetryInitializer to the TelemetryConfiguration)

Failed or not can be determined from RequestTelemetry and DependencyTelemetry from their `Success` field.

(the last one in FAQ sections has hints to answer your question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#frequently-asked-questions)
```

Comment: btw - you can use the above with AdaptiveSampling. In most cases AdaptiveSampling works best, and is the default sampling enabled in asp.net and asp.net core apps.